# Oozie Job is failing

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, oozie

I am attempting to run a simple Oozie job to pull data from a local MySQL database using Sqoop. Below is my workflow.xml:

```
<workflow-app name="sqoopoozietest" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
<start to="sqoopconnect"/>
<action name="sqoopconnect">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>horton-n2.hdp.local:8050</job-tracker>
        <name-node>hdfs://horton-n1.hdp.local:8020</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="hdfs://horton-n1.hdp.local:8020/user/mannb/sqoopoozie/sqoopinput"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <command>import  --connect jdbc:mysql://horton-n1.hdp.local/sqooptest --table sampledata --username sqoop --password sqoop123 --target-dir --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver hdfs://horton-n1.hdp.local:8020/user/mannb/sqoopoozie/sqoopinput -m 1</command>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to = "sqoopend"/>
    <error to = "kill"/>
</action>

   <kill name = "kill">
        <message>"Workflow failed."</message>
   </kill>

   <end name = "sqoopend" />
</workflow-app>
```

The main error I'm receiving an error from /var/log/oozie.log:

javax.servlet.jsp.el.ELException: The function "wf:errorMessage" requires 1 arguments but was passed 0

I thought this was strange since I am passing an argument to the kill name message: "Workflow failed.".

Below is my job.properties file:

```
nameNode=hdfs://horton-n1.hdp.local:8020
jobTracker=horton-n2.hdp.local:8050

queueName=default
#oozie.use.system.libpath=true

oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/mannb/sqoopoozie/workflow.xml
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below.

```
 <error to = "kill_job"/>

 <kill name = "kill_job">
        <message>Workflow failed</message>
 </kill>
```

Comment: I made this change, and still getting the same error in oozie.log. I uncommented #oozie.use.system.libpath=true from job.properties too, since commenting it out caused an issue with finding the Sqoop .jars.

Comment: I had an error in my sqoop import command. After correcting it, it ran successfully, still unsure as to why the error code wouldn't return properly. This distracted me from the main issue. Thanks for your inputs, though.

Comment: This distracted me as well, but in error scenario it should work , you may have to double check once.